# Python: How to save log file toSharePoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I currently have a log in my Python Script as follows:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename = 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Pilot_Log.txt', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

Rather than saving the log file onto a user's local drive, I want to be able to save it straight onto a SharePoint. I tried something like this but it fails:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename = 'https:\\office2.xyz.com\\sites\\Test\\Shared Documents\\Pilot_Log.txt', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

How can I save the log file straight onto a SharePoint?

Comment: Have you tried [www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/9388/how-to-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-on-premises-using-python](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/9388/how-to-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-on-premises-using-python)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Rather than posting the URL of the log file from the browser, I opened the folder in Windows Explorer and right-clicked on the file and used the Location under Properties.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename = '\\\\office2.xyz.com@SSL\\DavWWWRoot\\sites\\Test\\Shared Documents\\Pilot_Log.txt', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

It worked as expected.